# NodeJS - Global variable's value hasn't changed

Tags: node.js

I want to implement a system in which if the user types domain/crypt/text (the page where the text gets crypted), the text is available to read in the main page (domain). I've found out the problem is that when I change the URL to check the main page datas gets resetted since I'm loading once again the page, but I can't find any solution to this problem.

```
const Encryption = require('node_triple_des');
const sha1 = require('sha1');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const key = "Chiave_scelta";
var coded_key = 'Coded_Key';
var text_crypted = 'NaN';
var text_decrypted = 'NaN';

async function encryptKey() {
  coded_key = sha1(key); //si codifica la chiave scelta in SHA1
}
async function encryptAll(msg) {
  await encryptKey();
  var result = await Encryption.encrypt(coded_key,msg);
  return result;
}
async function decryptAll(msg) {
  await encryptKey();
  var result = await Encryption.decrypt(coded_key, msg);
  return result;
}
  
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Generated key: ' + coded_key + '<br>' +
           'Last crypted text: ' + text_crypted + '<br>' +
           'Last decrypted text: ' + text_decrypted + '<br>'
  )
})
app.get('/crypt/:code', async function (req, res) {
  crypted_text = await encryptAll(req.params.code); //cripta il messaggio
  res.send('Crypted text: ' + crypted_text )
})
app.get('/decrypt/:code', async function (req, res) {
  decrypted_text = await decryptAll(req.params.code); //decripta il messaggio
  res.send('Decrypted text: ' + decrypted_text )
})
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: for global vars.. instead of using `var varName=value` just use `varName=value`.. like `codedKey="Chiave_scelta"`

Comment: I tried to remove the keyword var but it still doesn't display the coded text in the main page.

Comment: @TheBombSquad — No. Implicit globals are forbidden in strict mode.

Comment: i didn't see him use strict though.. but even so.. would `global.varName=value` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by importing the module 'local-storage' (which I previously installed).

```
const ls = require('local-storage');
```

To set values I used the following syntax:

```
ls.set(name,value);
```

To get values I used the following syntax:

```
ls.get(name,value);
```